# What's the difference between the usage of `curl` in my post?

Tags: curl

What's the difference between the below usage of `curl`?

```
curl -vo 1 'https://example.com' --resolve example.com:443:1.1.1.1
curl -vo 1 'https://1.1.1.1' -H 'host: example.com'
```

the `1.1.1.1` presents the example.com's A address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `curl` command-line fetches `https://demo.cc` with a fairly pointless `--resolve` option for `demo.com` (pointless because it's not the domain name for the URL being fetched).

The second fetches `https://1.1.1.1` and sets the `host:` request header to `demo.com`.

Depending on how the server at 1.1.1.1 is configured the second curl command **may** fetch the default page for `https://demo.com`.  But it probably won't - to start with, it's unlikely that Cloudflare's DNS resolver at 1.1.1.1 is configured to serve web pages for `demo.com` at all, and it's entirely possible that it will ignore the lowercase `host:` header (should be `Host:`, with a capital "H"), as some web servers are case-sensitive when it comes to recognising header names.

---

BTW, if you don't own `demo.com` or `demo.cc` then you shouldn't use them as examples, they belong to someone else.  Use `example.com` or `example.net` or `example.edu`, or `example.org` instead.  These domains exist solely to be used as examples and will never be assigned to anyone.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com